# Better way to get number from JSON file (other than jq)

Tags: json, bash

I've got this json:

```
# coverage/.last_run.json
{
  "result": {
    "covered_percent": 100.0
  }
}
```

I want to get the un-rounded integer (in this case, `100`) for the `covered_percent` key. I don't want to use `jq`, `ruby`, `python`, `perl`, etc., just simple unix tools that ship on a standard ubuntu installation. So far, I have this:

```
grep -o '"covered_percent":.*[0-9]*' coverage/.last_run.json | sed 's/"covered_percent": //g' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*//g'
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: Please write "Standard Unix tools are not suitable for processing JSON" one hundred times on the blackboard. _Use the right tool for the job._

Comment: `i=1; while [[ $i -le 100 ]]; do echo "Standard Unix tools are not suitable for processing JSON"; let i=i+1; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really don't want to use the `jq`, awk could be the answer:

```
$ awk '/covered_percent/ {print substr($0,match($0,/[0-9]+/),RLENGTH)}' file
100
```

Serializing `grep`s could also do the trick:

```
$ grep covered_percent file | grep -o [1-9][0-9]* | head -1
```

`head` is needed as for `99.99` `grep -o` returns:

```
99
99
```

Both solutions as such will fail for inputs < 1, such as `.9`, and print `9`. That can be fixed by prepending the regexen with `[^.]`.

But remember, that Standard Unix tools are not suitable for processing JSON, Standard Unix tools are not suitable for processing JSON, Standard Unix tools are not suitable for processing JSON, ...

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there are definitely better tools for the job, and I will use one of them for the actual task. I'm working on getting better at shell scripting and it seemed like a good academic exercise.